# Get access to removable SD Android

Tags: java, android

To begin, excuse my English.

I would like to know how it is that the RAR application can obtain permissions to write about the removable SD without going through the storage access framework of android, only with this dialog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUq3Y.jpg

I have a project in which I use the Storage Access Framework so that people can download files in the removable SD, but sometimes they tend to mess up a bit and this makes me a better solution, but I have no idea how, someone could explain me a little .

Comment: there is no other solution except using *stupid* SAF

Comment: That dialog does use SAF. If you wish to use it still, I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972905/android-r-w-to-removable-sd-card/54975343#54975343

Comment: Is there any way to do the same but in java?