# Read file from micro SD card in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sd-card

How to read a file from a micro SD card in android?
Is there a unique path to get the micro SD card path? if yes, what is then?
What trick can I use to get the micro SD card path to be able to read a file from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access External Micro SD card of the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716448/how-to-access-external-micro-sd-card-of-the-phone)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972905/android-r-w-to-removable-sd-card/54975343#54975343

Answer (score 0):

some might suggest using `/sdcard` but you should use this instead:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Comment: this method does not exactly return the Micro SD Card path. I wrote a text file using this method, it was saved in my phone storage, not on micro sd card.

Comment: I tested this. It returns the path to the primary storage (I mean the storage of the device itself). But I want to return the path to Micro SD card (External Memory).