Write to external removable SD Card since API 30
How to access and write files (PDF, DB, CSV) on an external SD Card since API 30.
I checked :

Storage Access Framework (SAF) => Didn't found any SD Card sample
Without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE => Found nothing

The people from the Android Storage Dev team, if you see this message, the usage and the documentation of SAF is chaotic between all the version.

Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972905/android-r-w-to-removable-sd-card ?

"Storage Access Framework (SAF) => Didn't found any SD Card sample" -- the Storage Access Framework allows the user to choose what to work with, and the user can choose removable storage if the user desires. There is no "SD card sample", because the Storage Access Framework behaves the same from your app's standpoint regardless of where the content is stored.

@Pawel Yes, that why access and write are in bold.

@CommonsWare OK, but if he wants on the device in "Documents" and as backup on the SDCard, how to set up all the providers (intern and external) to get it working? Do you have any examples in your book ?

"how to set up all the providers (intern and external) to get it working?" -- I do not know what you mean by "providers" in this case. You ask the user for the primary location (in your scenario, Documents) and then you ask the user where to place a backup (in your scenario, removable storage). That requires two Storage Access Framework requests, using either ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE depending on your needs.

"Do you have any examples in your book ?" -- I show the use of the Storage Access Framework in this chapter of this free book. I also cover it in this chapter of this free book.
